# unable to get Am Pm from date object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having date Object in javascript , by this date object I am trying to get `AM` , or `PM`. Here is date Object `Mon May 01 2017 12:43:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

According to time it should return `pm` as it is 12:43 noon as per Indian Standard Time.But returning 'am'

And here is my logic

```js
var x = new Date("Mon May 01 2017 12:43:30 GMT+0530"); // (India Standard Time)
var hours = x.getHours();
var hours = (hours + 24 - 2) % 24;
var amPmStr = ' am';
if (hours == 0) { //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
  hours = 12;
} else if (hours > 12) {
  hours = hours % 12;
  amPmStr = ' pm';
}
console.log(amPmStr,x)
```

Comment: `var hours = (hours+24-2)%24; ` <-- What are you doing there?

Comment: Do you still face the problem or have you solved it?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen still there is problem , now I am trying like  var amPmStr = hours >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am';

Comment: @glenmaxwell did you check my answer if you have, why haven't you made a comment about what's not working with it.

Comment: as u can see it is alredy showing am instead of pm.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, Hope this can guide you in the right direction

I've removed the "-2" from `var hours = (hours + 24 - 2) % 24;` Since it don't make sense to have it.

```js
var x = new Date("05 01 2017 12:43:30")
var hours = x.getHours();
var minutes = x.getMinutes();
hours = (hours + 24) % 24;
var amPmStr = ' am';
if (hours < 12) { //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
  hours = 12;
} else if (hours >= 12 && minutes > 00) {
  hours = hours % 12;
  amPmStr = ' pm';
}

console.log(amPmStr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```